# Footer Page Links

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to have something like this at the bottom of my chrome extension:
https://gyazo.com/89f5f73f1f4fc24a764c058dbfee24de

Mine currently looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/f71a60149cc0301f965e7f0736815505

This is my html code:
https://gyazo.com/2fb446ed0b7fd61bde06d201f175495d

What should I do to get mine looking like the first one.

Comment: Btw, this is where the aqua background comes from:
https://gyazo.com/aca22dbd61256ebe4b5f7376ea28406f

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would want to use CSS to solve this issue. The code of which should be found on [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_split_screen.asp). It should have all the information on how to split the footer in half. You would also want to take the background color out of the CSS as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help homie!

Here's the solution i ended up with:
https://gyazo.com/300cce939773d85873a022a7258d15a8
https://gyazo.com/dfbf713a7b463737d3fb8728c96ac896

https://gyazo.com/ce02f8ed42105824f8f21e830593997f

Answer (score 0):

You need CSS for this. Add the class `footer` to the `td`

```css
td.footer{
 background-color: none;
}

td.footer a {
 color: aqua;
}
```